# Tkinter pack Entry Widgets Based On OptionMenu Value, pack_forget Otherwise

Tags: python, tkinter, trace, optionmenu, tkinter-entry

When `tk.OptionMenu` is equivalent to `CUSTOM`, the code below displays two `tk.Entry` fields.  How does one hide the `tk.Entry` fields from view after a `tk.OptionMenu` is selected that's not `CUSTOM`?

For example, the code below displays two fields if user selects `CUSTOM` from the dropdown, but if the user goes to select another option, I want to remove the two fields that were added from view and display them again if `CUSTOM` is selected from the dropdown again. In a sense, toggle them.

My research has turned up **pack_forget**, **destroy**, **trace**. I can't seem to figure it out.

[image: tkinter]

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

def func(*args):
  if date_var.get() == 'CUSTOM':
    new_frame = tk.Frame(frame)
    new_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    field1 = tk.Entry(new_frame)
    field2 = tk.Entry(new_frame)
    field1.pack()
    field2.pack()
  else:
    try:
      new_frame.destroy()
    except:
      pass

date_var = tk.StringVar()
date_var.trace('w', func)
date_var.set('LAST_10_DAYS')
date_options = ['CUSTOM', 'LAST_10_DAYS', 'LAST_50_DAYS', 'LAST_10_MILLION_YEARS']
date = tk.OptionMenu(frame, date_var, *date_options)
date.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What happens when you try `pack_forget` or `destroy`? I'm guessing you get an error. What does it say? What can you learn from it?

Comment: I don't receive an error. The code above is packing `field1` and `field2` every time `CUSTOM` was selected. That makes sense logically now. My primary gap in understanding (being new to tkinter) was understanding the placement of operations. I got a solution to work. I'll post it now. BTW, your code examples here on SO are extremely helpful. An answer of yours shows up in just about every tkinter search I do!

Comment: Actually there was an exception earlier in your code, if you change the `except` with this - `except Exception, e: print e`, it will print the exception message. `new_frame` was local to the function.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by putting `field1` and `field2` in a `new_frame` (`tk.Frame`) **outside of the function**. Then I let an if statement determine whether to `pack` or `pack_forget` `new_frame` based on the value from the `OptionMenu`. Can't say if this is the best way but it works for now.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

new_frame = tk.Frame(frame)
field1 = tk.Entry(new_frame)
field2 = tk.Entry(new_frame)
field1.pack()
field2.pack()

def func(*args):
  if date_var.get() == 'CUSTOM':
    new_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
  else:
    new_frame.pack_forget()

date_var = tk.StringVar()
date_var.trace('w', func)
date_var.set('LAST_10_DAYS')
date_options = ['CUSTOM', 'LAST_10_DAYS', 'LAST_50_DAYS', 'LAST_10_MILLION_YEARS']
date = tk.OptionMenu(frame, date_var, *date_options)
date.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```